# Saving cURL and jq output to a variable in batch script

Tags: batch-file, curl, jq

I use this command in order to retrieve a result of a build in Jenkins:

```
curl -s  http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastCompletedBuild/api/json | jq ."result"
```

Based on that result I need to decide an action to be performed using a batch command,

How do I save the output of the command as a variable?

Comment: you're trying to use BASH syntax in a BATCH script. BATCH is a windows scripting system, BASH is used on unix systems. i believe the BATCH equivalent would be ```SET test= (curl -s  http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastCompletedBuild/api/json | jq ."result")  echo %test%``` , but no guarantee, i haven't done BATCH scripting in many years.

Comment: @hanshenrik  I have also tested this to no avail.

Comment: @compo  edited the question to be more clear .

Comment: the cURL command in combination of the jq that returns the value of "result" returns one of three values , I need to perform an action based on the value returned - for that I want to save it into a variable ,

Comment: @Compo - 
I will try to explain myself ,
I am trying to set the output of the command in the question as a variable so that i could perform different actions in the batch script based on the String value in the variable , 
the command returns either "Failed" , "Success" or "Unstable" , 
I want to know how to take the output of the command and insert it into a variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `For /F` command in a batch file to return the output of a command to a variable:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"curl -s  http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastCompletedBuild/api/json | jq ."result""') Do Set "test=%%~A"
If /I "%test%"=="failed" ...DoSomething
If /I "%test%"=="success" ...DoSomethingElse
If /I "%test%"=="unstable" ...DoAnotherThing
```

However there may be no need to set a variable at all, because you can work with the returned metavariable directly:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
    "curl -s  http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastCompletedBuild/api/json | jq ."result""
') Do (
    If /I "%%~A"=="failed" ...DoSomething
    If /I "%%~A"=="success" ...DoSomethingElse
    If /I "%%~A"=="unstable" ...DoAnotherThing
)
```